# How do I connect to a MySQL Database in Python with a RaspberryPi

Tags: python, mysql, database, intellij-idea, raspberry-pi

I'm a student and I'm trying to write some sensor values into a MySQL database.

As IDE I'll be using Inteliji.
First off I started by installing the database Plug-in.

- This was done successfully

Next I tried to connect to the data base (see figure below)

[Figure of successful connection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MubFi.png)

Now The next thing I want to do is use a MySQL connector.
Therefore I've installed MySQL onto the r-PI and used following code to implement it.

```
import mysql.connector
print("Step 1")
cnx = mysql.connector.connect(user='user', 
                              password='secret',
                              host='host',
                              database='db')
Print("Step 2")
```

When now I run my code the terminal will output:

```
Step1
```

For some reason I don't know; the connect function always times my program out with the next occurring errors:

```
mysql.connector.errors.InterfaceError: 2003: Can't connect to MySQL server on 'mysql.studev.groept.be:3306' (110 Connection timed out)
```

So does anyone know why my connection is successful but I can't connect to it?
Long story short what am I doing wrong and how do I fix this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The problem is connection between rpi and db. Check your internet connection on rpi - Are you on wifi? Ethernet cable? Or are you connected with your dev computer? If the latter, remember you have to bridge your connection to share your own internet access with rpi

Comment: I'm using my laptop as a NAT router between the r-PI and the database. I've shared the Wi-Fi my laptop is connected to to my r-PI. So I can communicate with the r-PI trough SSH

Comment: Could this be the problem:
Since the database is private to our campus network we have to use a VPN. 
However when NOT connected trough the VPN we CAN'T access the db.
If we ARE connected we CAN access the db.
Right now I CAN access the database in IntelliJ and even change values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your timeout means the network on your rPi cannot reach -- cannot find a route to -- your MySQL host `mysql.studev.groept.be`.

If you do `traceroute mysql.studev.groept.be` in a shell in the rPi you may see what's wrong.

When in a shell on your rPi, can you ssh to any machine in your uni's network? If so, you might be able to use ssh port-forwarding to get a route to the database server.

Do you run intelliJ on the rPi directly, or on your laptop? If you run it on the laptop, it looks like the laptop can find a route to your server but the rPi cannot.

(If this were my project, I'd install a MySQL server on my laptop to reduce the network-engineering hassles of connecting through multiple hops involving a VPN.)

Comment: I see what you're saying. I'm using IntelliJ on my laptop and when I traceroute the database host in my r-Pi shell it exceeds it's time-to-live (30 hops). My original plan was: 
the r-Pi is in the network, the DB is in the network. I'll be acting like a router. By first configuring the r-Pi trough serial communication I could connect it to the DB network by sharing my Wi-Fi (which is the a connection into the DB network). I have not fixed my problem yet. But your insight was very helpful. I'll go to the campus right now and try to leave out the VPN and maybe that'll fix it.
Thank O. Jones

Comment: Good. VPNs are a pain in the *** neck when multiple machines need to connect over them.

Comment: I'm on campus, and as usual. It works, the VPN was the problem. I think I shared the wrong Wi-Fi. Instead of sharing the VPN I think I shared the Wi-Fi of the residence I'm staying at. With your insight I've solved the problem. 

Thank you very much O. Jones!!!

Comment: rPis are nice. You can put them in your pocket and take them where they need to be.

Comment: `can you ssh to any machine in your uni's network? If so, you might be able to use ssh port-forwarding to get a route to the database server` -> just tunnel through your own laptop because it got access ;D I did that a lot - I had linux main os and windows vm where I run vpn client (because some vpn clients are only on windows and mac, and if there are on linux they are bugged), so I used vm to connect to vpn, then ssh with tunnel from main os :D